# How to stop html images moving?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

My img's move when i resize the browser or try a different resolution - the images stay grouped in the same places ie one stays under the other but they all move to the left when the resolution is changed or the browser is zoomed in or out.
Code:

```
    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#trimmings">
    <h3 style="width:200px;  margin-left:620px;  border-radius:5px; margin-top:-110px; position:relative;"><font color="black"> Trimmings & tassels</h3>


  <img  alt="trimmings" id="trimmingslink" style="width:200px; margin-left:610px;              margin-top:-0px; border-radius:5px; position:relative;;" src="img/interiors/Trimmings&Tassels3.jpg">
  </font>
    </div></a>
    </div>

    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#tracksandpoles">
    <h3 style="width:200px; margin-left:985px; margin-top:-295px; margin-bottom:20px;  border-radius:5px; " src="img/interiors/tracks&poles.jpg"><font color="black">Tracks & poles</h3>

  <img alt="tracks and poles" id="trackslink" style="width:200px; margin-left:950px; margin-bottom:3px;  border-radius:5px; " src="img/interiors/tracks&poles.jpg">
  </font>
  </div></a>

<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#wallcoverings">
    <h3 ><font color="black">Wall coverings</h3>
  <img alt="wall coverings" id="wallcoveringslink" style="width:200px;  margin-bottom:3px; margin-left:11.5px; border-radius:5px; " src="img/interiors/wallcoverings.jpg">
  </font>
  </div></a>

<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#fabrics">
<h3 ><font color="black">Fabrics</h3>
  <img alt="fabrics"  id="fabricslink" style="width:200px; margin-left:11.5px; margin-bottom:3px; border-radius:5px; " src="img/interiors/Fabric2.jpg">
    </font>
    </div></a>

    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#Decorative">
<h3 ><font color="black">Decorative antiques</h3>
  <img alt="antiques" style="width:200px; margin-left:11.5px; margin-bottom:3px; border-radius:5px; id="interiorslink6" "src="img/interiors/Decorative2.jpg">
  </font>
  </div></a>
```

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla - whilst you're absolutely correct, this comment isn't helpful.

Comment: @aphextwix , just wanted to convey the issue, maybe the messed up code is a problem, i cant write the correct code by myself, as it is unclear what ui the OP is trying to built.

Comment: Exactly, what you wanted to do ? Be specific. with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) code for HTML | CSS | jquery

Comment: Jscomputing Services - can you be more specific in your question with regards to how many images you would like in your grid? For example 4 x 4 images

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't be using inline styles for CSS, and instead should be using external stylesheets. See this article for more information - https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/inline-vs-internal-vs-external-css/

Comment: the images are links to a pop up box and there are five of them with titles i just need it so there in the same places on all resolutions

Comment: @JscomputingServices - and you would like them to all stay on the same row when the browser window is resized?

Comment: yes just so they stay in the same place with two on the top two below the first two and one on the bottom in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible layout :

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    margin:2%;
    width: 46%;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
```

So each of your `popup-with-zoom-anim` sections can be inserted inside the `item` divs, making your cleaned up HTML look like so :

```
<div class="item">
    <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#fabrics">
       <h3 >Fabrics</h3>
       <img alt="fabrics"  id="fabricslink" src="img/interiors/Fabric2.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```